# Who is the owner of a relationship?

Tags: uml

According to UML specs every `Element` can have an owner. Whether he has/must have an owner is determined by method `mustBeOwned(): Boolean`, which by default is `true` (see 7.8 Classifier Descriptions in [specs](http://omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/)).

In cases when an element is completely enclosed by its owner (such as a class in a package) it is quite obvious.

However for relationships (normal, directed, generalization, …) I didn't find any specification. Is the "source" (for directed at least) also the owner?

Is it the first common owner in the ownership chain? So for example association between two classes in a same package, the owner of the association would be the package.

Or is it simply not defined and it can be whatever I want?

[image]

Comment: Typically, a package owns associations and Typically, a package owns associations and generalizations. . I believe the rules you're asking about are in the namespaces section, and your question is about named elements. I don't have the spec with me to verify my memory right now, so I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer. Maybe I'll have time later today, but I wanted to at least give you a hint that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the definition of terms in Superstructures is still very poor.

Looking closer it's even worse (citing from ptc 13-09-05).

**Relationships** (p. 15)

> A Relationship is an Element that specifies some kind of relationship between other Elements. Descendants of Relationship provide semantics appropriate to the concept they represent.

**Connector** (p. 235)

> A Connector specifies links that enables communication between two or more instances. In contrast to Associations, which specify links between any instance of the associated Classifiers, Connectors specify links between instances playing the connected parts only.

I wasn't aware that they made a difference between both. Appears to be quite picky.

**Association** (p. 206)

> An Association classifies a set of tuples representing links between typed instances. An AssociationClass is both an Association and a Class.

No mentioning of `Relationship` as being a parent.

Now seeking for the truth about `owner`

**owner** (p. 37)

> /owner : Element [0..1]{union} (opposite Element::ownedElement) The Element that owns this Element.

**mustBeOwned** (a bit down)

> mustBeOwned() : Boolean
>   The query mustBeOwned() indicates whether Elements of this type must have an owner. Subclasses of Element that do not require an owner must override this operation.

So here one is stuck unless reading to

**Association** (p 209)

> Ownership of Association ends by an associated Classifier may be indicated graphically by a small filled circle, which for brevity we will term a dot. The dot is to be drawn integral to the graphic path of the line, at the point where it meets the Classifier, inserted between the end of the line and the side of the node representing the Classifier. The diameter of the dot shall not exceed half the height of the aggregation diamond, and shall be larger than the width of the line. This avoids visual confusion with the filled diamond notation while ensuring that it can be distinguished from the line. The dot shows that the model includes a Property of the type represented by the Classifier touched by the dot. This Property is owned by the Classifier at the other end. In such a case it is normal to suppress the Property from the attributes compartment of the owning Classifier.

### Answer?

Most likely (!) connectors do not have the `mustBeOwned` constraint and *can*  be owned in which case you will see the dot that has been introduced with 2.5. Else they are probably not owned.

Comment: I was under the impression that `Connector` is related to component diagrams. What I had in mind is... if you have `Generalization` line between two classes, then someone must own the generalization. Or is it actually `Connector` of type `Generalization`? It's little bit confusing.

Comment: Now you got me. I have to withdraw my answer :-/ Will have to read more thoroughly too.

Comment: Instead, I have re-written my 'answer'. Hope it helps, though.

Comment: thanks, it helps for now :), but it seems I will have to read the specs cover to cover to internalize all those terms... because right now it makes my head hurt :(

Comment: The specs are no bed-time lecture, unfortunately. My advice in most cases: don't take the spec too serious. Let your feelings guide you. As long as you can transport a message with your model it's fine. When people start asking it's a good sign. Discuss and see where you can get a point of agreement.

Comment: An Association's ends are instances of Property and their ownership is not the same as the ownership of the association.  Connectors are irrelevant because they denote ownership of Properties and not of Associations.  Of course, the obfuscatory nature of the spec makes me question every conclusion...

Comment: @Huliax true. Though the specs have improved there is still a lot of room for improvement. To me Superstructures is still not an example for a good documentation - so to say. Too many cooks spoil the broth.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the relation is generally not owned by elements it connects. What is owned is the association (relationship) end's and corresponding attributes/properties. Section 6.4.2. of UML specification 2.4.1 clarified this much better than your linked 2.5 beta. I would suggest that you use the current official version of specs rather than the beta one. I find the 2.5 being kind of unintelligible, the table of contents looks very chaotic.

The Relationship itself exists independently, it has no owner. Except when stated otherwise by concrete type of relationship (as in case of Generalization).

Which brings me to the main point of my answer by question. Why do you need to know?

I have been reading and explaining the specification for years now, but never came across such a specific question, which moreover is relatively clearly stated in the specs.

I would recommend to look at concrete relations and search (Ctrl+F) for "owned" (an Association has more than a page of text on this very topic in detail starting on page 40 in 2.4.1).

Answer (score 0):

I myself have been trying to figure out what can own an instance of Association.  I am using 2.4.1.  This appears to me to be a(nother) case of the standard not actually being usable.

I haven't looked at all of the specializations of Relationship.  I have looked at Association.  It inherits *owner* from Element.  The property is noted as a derived union.  I can't find any property of Association (or any of its antecedents) that subsets *owner*.  That being the case, I don't see how Association can actually have an owner.

I think that it seems reasonable for a Package to own an association.

I am using a UML tool that certainly does initialize the value of *owner* for associations.  I am programmatically interpreting models created in that tool and using them as input for other modeling tools that I am working on.  The makers of the first tool obviously had to just make up / guess at things and now I have to decide whether what they did was actually rational and if I want to agree with their conclusions (which happen to allow Classifiers to own Associations, which I think is weird) or do something else. Thanks OMG. Grrrr.

I wonder if older versions of the spec were any more clear?